# Bash script how to sleep in new process then execute a command

Tags: linux, bash

So, I was wondering if there was a bash command that lets me fork a process which sleeps for several seconds, then executes a command.

Here's an example:

```
sleep 30 'echo executing...' &
```

^This doesn't actually work (because the sleep command only takes the time argument), but is there something that could do something like this? So, basically, a sleep command that takes a time argument and something to execute when the interval is completed? I want to be able to fork it into a different process then continue processing the shell script.

Also, I know I could write a simple script that does this, but due to some restraints to the situation (I'm actually passing this through a ssh call), I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can invoke another shell in the background and make it do what you want:

```
bash -c 'sleep 30; do-whatever-else' &
```

The default interval for sleep is in seconds, so the above would sleep for 30 seconds. You can specify other intervals like: `30m` for 30 minutes, or `1h` for 1 hour, or `3d` for 3 days.

Answer (score 66):

You can do

```
(sleep 30 && command ...)&
```

Using `&&` is safer than `;` because it ensures that `command ...` will run only if the sleep timer expires.

Comment: This does not exit the out of the current line, is there a way to add CTRL+C to it when done